# Почему после изменения значение переменной типа String не меняется соответственно значению в arrayList использующем эту переменную

Tags: java, строки, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> be = new ArrayList<>();

String s1 = new String("sun");
String s2 = new String("mon");
String s3 = new String("tu");
String s4 = new String("wed");

be.add(s1);
be.add(s2);
be.add(s3);
be.add(s4);

for (String st : be)
    {System.out.println(st);}

s1 = null;
System.out.println("___________________________1_____________________");
for (String st : be)
    {System.out.println(st);}   // print sun mon tu wed


s2 = "NU";


 System.out.println("__________________________2_____________________");
for (String st : be)
    {System.out.println(st);}   

// print sun mon tu wed

be.remove(s4);


System.out.println("___________________________4_____________________");
for (String st : be)
    {System.out.println(st);}

// print sun mon tu
```

Почему то, что содержит ArrayList не изменяется, если он содержит переменные?

Следующий код доказывает что ArrayList cодержит references на объекты и когда заменяем обЪект то содержимое  ArrayList меняется. Почему это не происходит в первом примере?...
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ArrayList <Person> a = new ArrayList <>();

    Person p1 = new Person("Dasha");
    Person p2 = new Person("Masha");

    a.add(p1);
    a.add(p2);


    ArrayList<Person> a2 = a;

    p1.name = "Lilla";

    for (Person p : a) {

        System.out.println(p.name);


    }

    for (Person p : a2) {

        System.out.println(p.name);


    }



}
```

}class Person {

```
String name;
Person(String st){name = st;}
```

}
OUTPUT:
Lilla
Masha
Lilla
Masha

Comment: Вы ничего не меняете в Arraylist, причем здесь переменные?

Comment: Я добавляю переменную      ->      be.add(s1);       s1 = reference                                                 А не String                               ->         be.add("sun");

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, в Java строки неизменяемы. Во-вторых, присваивая новую ссылку на объект какой-либо переменной, вы не изменяете объект, на который эта переменная ссылалсь раньше. Инструкция `s2 = "NU"` создаёт новую строку и присваивает ссылку на неё переменной `s2`, но не изменяет исходную строку, на которую ссылается список.

Comment: А во втором примере изменяет исходную строку на которую ссылается список. Вот почему по разному это работает ..?

Comment: Во втором примере исходная строка тоже не изменяется. Создаётся новая строка и присваивается полю `name` экземпляра класса `Person`. То есть изменяется объект `p1`.

Comment: Если делать первый и второй пример кода эквивалентными, то вам надо сделать так `p1 = new Person("Lilla")`. В этом случае цикл тоже выведет строку "Dasha Masha".

Comment: Здорово, понятно, спасибо большое!!

Comment: @StephanieLisker [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

У Вас есть отдельно четыре переменных типа String со своими значениями. Когда вы заполняете List, то фактически создаёте список переменных ссылающихся на те же объекты. Как вам известно, String immutable и выражение

```
String str = "old string";
String str_1 = str;
str = "new stroka";
```

не изменит старую строку а создаст новую и str_1 по прежнему будет равно "odl string". Поэтому при присвоении наружной строке нового значения ей присваивается ссылка на новый объект, в то время как в листе сохраняется переменная со ссылкой на старый.

Во втором случае у вас имеется две переменных со ссылкой на один объект Person с полем name. Вы можете менять значение name как у персоны снаружи так и внутри списка, но обе эти ссылки будут указывать на один и тот же объект.